# Is Petersen coil in resonant network tuned also for capacitor banks?

Tags: grounding, network, distribution-network, resonant, capacitor-banks

Petersen coil is tuned every 2-3 minutes to compensate for a certain percentage of capacitive current in resonant grids during earth faults. But, if capacitor banks with ground connection are switched on in the resonant grid, is Petersen coil tuned to compensate also this capacitive current during a single phase to ground fault?

Answer (score 1):

It is not corrected during an arc but during a feeder switch or environmental changes in moisture content in the air.  Matching the C impedance of the lines to earth in resonance serves to suppress the arc from continuing with high back EMF from a non-resonant inductive line. Here we are talking about the common-mode impedance of all lines to gnd and not the grid differential impedance.

My understanding is the Peterson coil shunts the Neutral of a WYE or "star" transformer to the ground such that it has an only equal impedance of the grid to earth at the line frequency and not the line to line passive p.f. correction caps.

Transmission lines might be something like 30 nF/km per phase.

The advantage of this is that it lowers the impedance of a ground fault to reduce the energy of an arc impulse but provides conjugate impedance matching after the impulse finishes to prevent oscillations on the grid.  Since at resonance the phase shift is 0 for series LC but it is in parallel normally with high leakage resistance. However it is done, there is some phase error with air moisture effects on C would be sensed then periodically corrected by tap changing the inductance.

This rate of change is controlled to extend the life of the relay contacts with normal operation, which might have a cumulative lifetime limit on Amp^2-cycles, just like any relays.

As feeders are switched with different lengths, then the (massive) Arc Suppression Coil or ASC’s inductive reactance has to be adjusted.    (they are not little coils)

https://electrical-engineering-portal.com/arc-suppression-coil-petersen-coil

Since rain or water has a Dk or \$\mu_R~\$of 80, the concentration of moisture will affect the capacitance.

Comment: Stwart EE75 thank you for your answer! A question: what do you mean with "Dk or miu_R of 80"?

Answer (score 1):

A 30 Mvar cap bank on, say, a 69 kV would be a capacitive reactance of,

$$X_C=\frac{69^2}{30}=-j158.7\Omega$$

which is a capacitance of (on 60Hz system),
$$C=\frac{1}{2\pi60(158.7)}=16.7\mu F$$

That would dwarf the small parasitic phase-ground capacitance of the ungrounded distribution feeders if connected solid-grounded wye.  So, where applied on resonant grounded systems (Peterson coil) the cap bank would be ungrounded wye or delta and out of the picture for zero-sequence (ground faults).